# Is this a Hyperbola or Ellipse inscribed or escribed around triangle?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The vertices of a triangle are $(5, 3)$ and $(5, -5)$. Determine the equation of the locus of the third vertex if the perimeter of the triangle is $20$ units.

[image]

So I assume $5$ units to be the major segment where $b$ is the minor segment, and $3$ units is the distance to foci.

By Pythagoras, I got:

$a^2=b^2+c^2$

$b= 4$ units

But still, I can't get the right locus of points given with the choices. So I was thinking if the locus of points escribing or inscribing the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let  $A=(5, 3)$ and $B=(5, -5)$. Let $P=(x,y)$ be the third point. Now impose that the perimeter of the triangle is $20$:
$$\mbox{dist}(A,P)+\mbox{dist}(B,P)+8=20.$$
Recall that an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) is a plane curve such that the sum of the distances to the two focal points is constant for every point on the curve.

Answer (score 1):

Your figure is not correct because the points $(5,3)$ and $(5,-5)$ are the foci of the ellipse. What you have is the center of the ellipse given by the midpoint $(5,-1)$. This said you that the ellipse is "vertical" instead of "horizontal".

You have the equation which is the definition itself of the ellipse as a locus
$$\sqrt{(x-5)^2+(y-3)^2}+\sqrt{(x-5)^2+(y+5)^2}=20-8=12$$ Simplifying you get
$$9(x-5)^2+5(y+1)^2=180$$
An ellipse "vertical" as you can verify.